# Android video saving with 1000x the required space

Tags: android, video

I made this code for saving making videos in my app but for some reason that I don't understand it is saving them with 1000x more space usage than necessary.

I know of this because the same video is being saved in the camera folder with 1000x less space usage.

any ideas? code is below.

```
    public void trabalhaVideo(Intent data) {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)
            && (!Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated())) {

        Uri vid = data.getData();
        String videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid);
        File file = new File(videoPath);

        try {
            File local = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/MEDGRUPO/videos/");

            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(videoPath);

            if (!local.exists()) {
                local.mkdirs();
                File novo = new File(local, cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".mp4");
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(novo);
                byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                fileInput.read(bFile);
                fileInput.close();
                for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
                    outStream.write(bFile);
                }
                outStream.close();

            } else {
                File novo = new File(local, cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".mp4");
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(novo);

                byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                fileInput.read(bFile);
                fileInput.close();
                for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
                    outStream.write(bFile);
                }
                outStream.close();
            }
            CustomAdapter.pintaLinha(ViewDeAtividades.getChildAt(2));
            AtividadesDAO dao = new AtividadesDAO(getApplicationContext());
            dao.atualizaAtividadeFeita(atividadeSelecionada);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Vídeo gravado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Where is your code **compressing** the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
                outStream.write(bFile);
            }
```

end up writing the entire bFile byte array bFile.length times. Effectively you are writing (bFile.length)<sup>2</sup> bytes. Just have one `outStream.write(bFile)`, you don't need to put it in a loop. If you insist on putting it in a loop then you loop should look like

```
           for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
                outStream.write(bFile[i]);
            }
```

Comment: thx for the help and sorry I took so long, somethings happened here.